# Choosing the right Model Associations in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I am having trouble deciding which type of association fits best for my application. I have the following models: `Firm`, `Client`, and `Case`.

A *Firm* handles many *Cases*. And each Case can have **one or more** *Clients* assigned to it. Therefore my initial approach was:

```
class Firm < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cases
   has_many :clients
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :firm
   has_many :clients
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :firm
   has_many :cases
end
```

But I think something is not right with this. I was thinking a `has_many :through` Association would be better but I am not sure.

Comment: Since a case can have many clients and a client can have many cases, a has_many_through association is needed. Can a Firm have a Case that does not belong to a Client?

Comment: No. A Case must always involve a Client.

Comment: @Jaime in client model, you must be storing case_id and firm_id..Am I right?

Comment: @margo If the Firms can have Clients without Cases, the `has_many :through` is not enough, is it? @Jaime : can a Client exists without cases?

Comment: It should be. The client case relationship doesnt have to be mandatory. Just make sure you define your through table and create the migrations.

Comment: @RORDeveloper No, because a client can belong to many cases, so it cannot contain a case_id. However, the client does contain firm_id because each Firm creates a profile for each of their clients.

Comment: @Mauddev Yes, a client can exist without a case. Because the Firm creates their clients first, and then when creating a new case they just select the clients from the existing created clients.

Comment: @Jaime Ok. Did you look in the doc about the case with Physicians, Patients and Appointments? If you can substitute those terms with Firm, Clients and Cases, than the `has_many :through` should work. See @margo's comments. It also explains where to put any foreign_keys. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Rails Guides says that “You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model”. As the great coding philosopher Avi Flombaum once eluded, how can you possibly know that your join model will not serve an additional purpose this early in the application process. No matter where you are in the development stage, you can never see so far in the future to know you will not need to extend the join table.
>
> > [Why You Don’t Need Has_and_belongs_to_many Relationships](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many)

With that out of the way:

```
# models/firm.rb
class Firm < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :clients
    has_many :cases, through: :clients
end

# models/client.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :firm
    has_many :client_cases
    has_many :cases, through: :client_cases
end

# models/case.rb
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :client_cases
    has_many :clients, through: :client_cases
end

# models/client_case.rb
class ClientCase < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :case
end
```

## UPDATE

Your issue must lie somewhere else; I was able to create the following in a terminal without any errors.

```
f = Firm.create name: 'Magical Group' # => #<Firm id: 1...
b = f.clients.create name: 'Billy' # => #<Client id: 1...
m = f.clients.create name: 'Megan' # => #<Client id: 2...
c = Case.create name: 'Billy & Megan are getting married!' # => #<Case id: 1...
b.cases << c # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
m.cases << c # => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
f.cases.count # => 2
f.cases.uniq.count # => 1
```

I've provide the database schema, make sure yours resembles:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150813173900) do

    create_table "cases", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end

    create_table "client_cases", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer  "client_id"
        t.integer  "case_id"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end

    add_index "client_cases", ["case_id"], name: "index_client_cases_on_case_id"
    add_index "client_cases", ["client_id"], name: "index_client_cases_on_client_id"

    create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.integer  "firm_id"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end

    add_index "clients", ["firm_id"], name: "index_clients_on_firm_id"

    create_table "firms", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end

end
```

Comment: This seems good, but if there might ever be a situation where a case can exist without having a client associated with it, then I'd add a direct association between Firm and Case also. I'd be tempted to anyway because I feel that there ought to be a way to do (for example) Firm.first.cases without needing to call uniq on the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am a bit confused why is there a need for a Case and a ClientCase Model?

Comment: This is essentially writing out a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. The `ClientCase` model acts as your joining table, just as a HABTM would have, and allows you more control over how you use your join model. I suggest you thoroughly read [the article](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/) I posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. One question however: What if I want to access all the casos in a Firm? Maybe perform a count, do an each, etc. How would I be able to achieve this in the view?

Comment: Because a `Firm` `has_many :cases, through: :clients` you can simply call `@firm.cases.uniq.count`

Comment: When I do this I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method class_name for nil:NilClass` error, but my models are defined exactly as in your answer...

Comment: @Jaime, I've created the environment exactly how I have in my answer and was able to produce the results in my updated answer.

Comment: @kjmagic13 Thank you for that detailed updated answer. So when I am creating a new `Case`, how do I assign the already existing clients? I plan on using the JQuery TokenInput plugin, but my question is really regarding the controller part. The reason I ask is because I see that you assign the case to the clients and not vice-versa.

Comment: @Jaime, it's just as easily done with `c.clients << [b, m]`. This takes a newly created Case, `c`, and adds two existing clients, `b` & `m`, to the case's clients. Also, to clarify, the array isn't necessary; you can assign one at a time like so: `c.clients << b`

Comment: Awesome! This works perfectly. One more question though:

Let's say I want to change the `Client` model to a `Person` model and make new `Client`, `Witness`, and `Counterpart` classes inherit from `Person`. They all have exactly the same information, how should I edit the associations in all the models?

Comment: @Jaime, That's a whole other beast. You'll have to ask that in a different question. Research Single Table Inheritance (STI). Would you be so kind as to mark my answer as the accepted answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a case will never belong to a different firm:

```
class Firm < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :clients
    has_many :cases, through: :clients
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :firm
    has_and_belongs_to_many :cases
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

Migrate join table
`rails g migration CreateJoinTableCaseClient case client`